# Request to merge tags [interpolation] and [interpolate]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-synonym-process

Both have exactly equivalent tag info wiki and excerpt. They are obviously a typographical variants of each other. Since [interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolation) has 1539 questions and [interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolate) – 161, and also on basis of their being an [extrapolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extrapolation) but not [extrapolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extrapolate) tag, I propose [interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolate) be made a tag synonym of [interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolation) and merged into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looked mainly to be for `scipy.interpolate`. [interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolate) -> [interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolation) merged and syn'd.